# FactoryGirl refer to factory_name in factory definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

i have a factories for Cities
i would like to add associations acording factory_name 
But i don't know how to refer to name in definition...

```
  factory :place do
    loc_geographic "-82.283204,29.320888"
    city "Some City"
    country 'USA'
    after(:build) do |place, eval|
      place.images << FactoryGirl.build("place_image_#{__FACTORY_NAME__}".to_sym)
    end
    factory :ny do
      city "New York"
    end
  end

  factory :place_image_ny, class: 'Place::Picture' do
    attachment {File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "/spec/fixtures/attachment/place_ny.jpg"))}
  end
```

Comment: what do you actually want instead of __FACTORY_NAME__. 'place' in this case ? ??

Comment: at **factory :ny** it should build image with **factory :place_image_ny** (eg  _after(:build) do |place, eval| place.images << FactoryGirl.build("place_image_ny".to_sym) end._  I have many factories like :ny, :boston, :orlando and etc and i want all them reuse behaviour of building association images using factory_name

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you are trying to DRY up your factory definition.

in your specific case, i don't think that it's necessary, but this example might just be a simplification of a more general usecase.

from what i know, it is not possible to access the factory name within the definition. i think that this might be for some good reason, but who knows...

there are several ways to do what you want:

1. use traits
2. use ignored attributes

both are described in this nice writeup: http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/factory_girl_tips.html

Comment: yes, i wanted to DRY up my factories because i have much places i need to test.. and in each definition i have to define same after create callback depending on factory name... It would be awesome if you share some example of using traits for my case...